# How to make entry texts to set fit to the entry box using Tkinter, Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been searching for help but was not able to find anything for what I needed..
I have something that looks like this:

[image]

So when the user input ingredients, it gets you the recipes online. Here, I want to fix the text box as it only shows one line. When I print out the output, it includes a new line and it looks nicer but once I insert this into the entry box, it ignores all new lines and spaces.
This is my code for the interface:

```
# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a GUI window
    master = tk.Tk()

    s = tk.StringVar()

    field1 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=s)
    field1.config({"background": "LightBlue1", "disabledbackground": "LightSkyBlue1"})
    field2 = tk.Entry(master)
    field2.config({"background": "Ivory", "disabledbackground": "Ivory"})

    field1.place(x=20, y=20, width=660, height=40)
    field2.place(x=20, y=80, width=660, height=500)

    field1.configure(state='disabled')
    field2.configure(state='disabled')

    # set font
    myFont = font.Font(family='Verdana', size=9, weight='bold')

    # set text message for cavas
    text = "Welcome to Recipe Finder!\n" \
           + "Instruction: Click the colored button,\n" \
           + "Type either sentence or words\n" \
           + "into the light blue box."

    canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=250, height=100, bg='DodgerBlue4')
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(x=700, y=40)
    canvas.create_text(125, 50, fill="white", font=myFont, text=text)

    # set the background colour of GUI window
    master.configure(background="lemon chiffon")

    # set the title of GUI window
    master.title("Recipe Finder")

    # set the configuration of GUI window
    master.geometry("970x600")

    # Buttons
    button1 = tk.Button(master, text=' Click for some food jokes! ', fg='black', bg='salmon',
                        command=foodJokes, height=5, width=30)
    button1.place(x=700, y=200)
    button1['font'] = myFont

    button2 = tk.Button(master, text=' Type the ingredients you have! ', fg='black', bg='orange',
                        command=askForIngredients, height=5, width=30)
    button2.place(x=700, y=300)
    button2['font'] = myFont

    Clear = tk.Button(master, text=' CLEAR ', fg='black', bg='white',
                      command=clear, height=5, width=30)
    Clear.place(x=700, y=400)
    Clear['font'] = myFont

    Enter = tk.Button(master, text=' ENTER ', fg='black', bg='white',
                      command=enter, height=5, width=30)
    Enter.place(x=700, y=500)
    Enter['font'] = myFont
```

Although I was told using "grid" is much simpler and better, I found "place" was working better for me... And I only saw the posts using grid and pack, which I do not want to change all my settings at this point. Is there a simple way to change the entry text to wrap texts inside the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a text widget instead of entry. Entry widgets do not allow text wrapping while text widgets do

Comment: Can I use text widget while I'm using place?

Comment: Yeah, you can use all widgets regardless of whether you are using place, grid or pack. I would really suggest using grid. It will make your code much more manageable

Comment: Ahh yes I was told.... when I tried to change them all to grid, I had a lot of issues so I just stayed with place. But from next projects I will try to use grid instead! And thank you! I used text widget and it looks so much better now!! :-D

Answer (score 0):

### On using `grid`

- Make a sketch (can be on paper) of how you want your user interface to look.
- Draw horizontal and vertical lines (red in the example below) *wherever* there is a separation between widgets.

In your example that would look like this:

[image: UI with grid lines]

In this case, all widgets span a single column. Two widgets (left bottom and right top) span multiple rows. When `grid`-ing those, you would use the `rowspan` argument indicate how many rows the widgets span.